# i can't understand this lambda functions

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

i am studying machine learning with python. 
and this code is from Standford Uiv classes. 
i was trying to grasp these codes but failed.

The problem is `loss_W = lambda W: self.loss(x,t)`.
isn't it True that loss_W(1) or loss_W(2) or anything cannot change the result?

i can't understand that the results of these two codes are different.

```
grads['W1'] = numerical_gradient(loss_W, self.params['W1']) 

grads['b1'] = numerical_gradient(loss_W, self.params['b1'])


def numerical_gradient(f, x):

    h = 1e-4 # 0.0001
    grad = np.zeros_like(x) 

    for idx in range(x.size):
        tmp_val = x[idx]

        # f(x+h) 
        x[idx] = float(tmp_val) + h
        fxh1 = f(x)

        # f(x-h) 
        x[idx] = tmp_val - h 
        fxh2 = f(x) 

        grad[idx] = (fxh1 - fxh2) / (2*h)
        x[idx] = tmp_val 

    return grad

class TwoLayerNet:

    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, weight_init_std=0.01):
        self.params = {}
        self.params['W1'] = weight_init_std * np.random.randn(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.params['b1'] = np.zeros(hidden_size)
        self.params['W2'] = weight_init_std * np.random.randn(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.params['b2'] = np.zeros(output_size)

    def predict(self, x):
        W1, W2 = self.params['W1'], self.params['W2']
        b1, b2 = self.params['b1'], self.params['b2']

        a1 = np.dot(x, W1)
        z1 = sigmoid(a1)
        a2 = np.dot(z1,W2)
        y = softmax(a2)

        return y

    def loss(self, x, t):
        y = self.predict(x)
        return cross_entropy_error(y,t)

    def accuracy(self, x,t):
        y = self.predict(x)
        y = np.argmax(y, axis=0)
        t = np.argmax(t, axis=0)
        data_len = len(x)
        accuracy = np.sum(y==t)/float(data_len)
        return accuracy

    def numerical_gradient(self, x, t):
        loss_W = lambda W: self.loss(x,t)

        grads = {}
        grads['W1'] = numerical_gradient(loss_W, self.params['W1'])
        grads['b1'] = numerical_gradient(loss_W, self.params['b1'])
        grads['W2'] = numerical_gradient(loss_W, self.params['W2'])
        grads['b2'] = numerical_gradient(loss_W, self.params['b2'])

        return grads
```

Comment: Um, is `numerical_gradient` defined as both a class member and a top-level function or something? I'm not talking about `_numerical_gradient` (which doesn't seem to be called at all).

Comment: sorry,  _numerical_gradient should be numerical_gradient . it was my miss
and i edit codes. thanks

Comment: Cool. So my question stands: how come you're defining `numerical_gradient` twice, as both a class member and a top-level function?

Comment: Yes. because the names are same i am confused too, i think numerical_gradient in the class method should be from the top-level function. (numerical_gradient(loss_W, self.params[])

Answer (score 0):

This lambda alone `loss_W = lambda W: self.loss(x,t)` is indifferent from the value of `W`. This function can be simplified like this:

```
x = 1 # Just some random value
t = 5 # Just some random value

def simplified_lambda_function(W):
    return (x,t)
```

The code snippet you posted indicates that there is a class definition outside somewhere as

```
grads['W1'] = numerical_gradient(loss_W, self.params['W1']) 

grads['b1'] = numerical_gradient(loss_W, self.params['b1']
```

`self` is undefined here. Because of this we cant be sure if they are truly identical, but most likely they are.

Comment: in your function though, the namespace is the global one (or outer one) and in the code provided by the OP it is the inner one; the one inside the function. So I am not sure if the two are actually equivallent.

Comment: Yes. I added some explanation about this. From the code provided we cant be sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
loss_W = lambda W: self.loss(x, t);
grads['W1'] = numerical_gradient(loss_W, self.params['W1']);
```

it can use self.params['W1'] to change loss's CEE to get grads['W1'], actually, self.params['W1'] will not change, but it will temporarily change to get cross_entropy_error(y, t)'s grad to achieve this goal which is get grads['W1'] by lambda function and numerical_gradient function